# how to send zip file as body in a post request in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

Let's say I have a zip file uploaded by user, how do I pass it to the server for process?

I have front end function to handle zip file. I can verify that fileUploaded holds the zip file.

```
  const onImport = async evt => {
    const fileUploaded = evt.target.files[0];
    const response = await extractImport('/extractimport', fileUploaded);
  };
```

Helper function used above

```
export const extractImport = async (url, fileUploaded) => {
  return await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'accept': 'application/zip'},
    body: fileUploaded
  });
};
```

router for post call.
And here, req body is empty. I don't know what went wrong here.

```
router.post('/extractimport',
  asyncWrapper(async (req, res) => {
    //req.body is empty here, I dont understand why.
    try {
      const result = await extractImportPost(req.body);
      res.status(200).json(result).end();
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({errors: [{error: err.message}]}).end();
    }
  })
);
```

extractImportPost utility used above is as below

```
const extractImportPost= async (zipFile) => {
  // zipFile is undefined here.
  // how do I pass the zip file to this place for process
}
```

Thank you for your time.